# Why is Namor part of the Illuminati?

Tags: marvel, marvel-illuminati

I understand why everyone else is there (power / intelligence), but I've been reading New Avengers and Namor doesn't seem to do anything but screw stuff up and generally be a butt. He doesn't even seem to bring much to the table power-wise. Why is he part of this otherwise elite group?

Comment: Per the Marvel Wikia; *"They each represented a certain something that was very special – Namor, of course, was the king of 71% of the planet, of the Atlanteans, and represented a certain mindset"*; http://marvel.wikia.com/Illuminati_%28Earth-616%29

Comment: He is arrogant and kind of a @#%!, true, but you're mistaken about the power part. Namor is one of the few characters who can go toe-to-toe with the Hulk & Thor.

Comment: Namor handed Iron Man's ass to him on a platter in Civil War and would've killed him if Dr. Strange hadn't interfered. Don't mistake Namor for Aquaman :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Namor's physical assets shouldn't be ignored in terms of capacity but what he brings to the Illuminati is history and experience.

- Namor's physical capacity puts him on par with Iron Man, the Hulk and other metahuman heavy hitters. Add his decades of experience in combat since his time in **[the Invaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invaders_%28comics%29)** and as a member of **[the Defenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defenders_(comics))** and he is more than formidable enough in any physical confrontation.
- He is, on most days, the undisputed ruler of seventy percent of the Earth's surface. In each member of the Illuminati's way, they are sovereigns or are uniquely qualified in one way or another.
- He has a great deal of experience in the Marvel Universe being one of the oldest members and having been active since World War II. His memories and experience with organizations like Hydra (whose origins are from WWII) can prove useful.
- But it is the history and longevity of his undersea kingdom which brings him most assuredly to the table. **[Atlantis](http://marvel.wikia.com/Atlantis)** has a 20,000 year history and likely knows or holds many secrets lost to the surface world due to that longevity alone. No other member can boast such an elite historical archive in terms of both science and magic.
- Namor's cantankerous nature also makes him an excellent Devil's Advocate always willing to argue the other side of any argument. His sharp mind and uncompromising perspective ensures his argument will cut right to the heart of the matter.

Comment: He's also the "first mutant".

Comment: @miltonaut: eh — [only in terms of real-world publication date, rather than in-universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namor#.22Marvel.27s_First_Mutant.22).

Comment: As Richard commented on the question, Namor also represents a certain mindset that the others don't have. In many ways he's the "5th man" who will represent the other side of the argument.